# ActivityEventListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNewIntent(Intent)

Tags: java, android, react-native

i am getting this error when **`build`** this is the full source of the file........................ below
this is a plug in for react native

full error as below
local/Android/src/main/java/com/kmlidc/RNShareLocal/RNShareLocalManager.java:51: error: RNShareLocalManager.RNShareLocalActivityEventListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNewIntent(Intent) in ActivityEventListener
    private class RNShareLocalActivityEventListener implements ActivityEventListener {

### ^

its a simple social sharing plugin

```
public class RNShareLocalManager extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener{
private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
private Callback callback;

final int SHARE_REQUEST = 500;

public RNShareLocalManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
    this.reactContext.addActivityEventListener(new RNShareLocalActivityEventListener());
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "RNShareLocal";
}

private class RNShareLocalActivityEventListener implements ActivityEventListener {
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == SHARE_REQUEST) {
            callback.invoke("success");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }
}

public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

}

@ReactMethod
public void message(String winTitle,String subject,String message,ReadableArray component, Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;

    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, winTitle);
    chooser.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    //是否指定App打开
    if(component != null && component.size() == 2) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(component.getString(0), component.getString(1)));
    }

    getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(chooser,SHARE_REQUEST);
}

@ReactMethod
public void link(String winTitle,String subject,String url,ReadableArray component, Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
    intent.setType("text/html");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, winTitle);
    chooser.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    //是否指定App打开
    if(component != null && component.size() == 2) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(component.getString(0), component.getString(1)));
    }

    getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(chooser,SHARE_REQUEST);
}

@ReactMethod
public void pictures(String winTitle,String subject,String message,ReadableArray imagesFile,ReadableArray component, Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for(int i=0; i<imagesFile.size();i++){
        uris.add(Uri.parse(imagesFile.getString(i)));
    }
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    intent.putExtra ("Kdescription", message);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, winTitle);
    chooser.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    //是否指定App打开
    if(component != null && component.size() == 2) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(component.getString(0), component.getString(1)));
    }

    getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(chooser,SHARE_REQUEST);
}

@ReactMethod
public void downloadImage(ReadableArray imagesUrl, Promise promise){
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<imagesUrl.size();i++){
        String imageUrl = imagesUrl.getString(i);
        String fileName = i + ".jpg";
        String path = this.download(imageUrl,fileName);
        paths.add(path);
    }

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(paths);
    promise.resolve(array.toString());
}

//下载图片并保存
public String download( String imageUrl, String fileName) {
    final String savePath = getReactApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir() + "/" + fileName;
    try {
        File f = new File(savePath);
        File dir = f.getParentFile();
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] data = getImage(imageUrl);
        os.write(data);
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

    return "file://" + savePath;
}

/*
* 获取网络图片
*/
public byte[] getImage(String imageUrl) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
    if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        return readStream(inStream);
    }
    return null;
}


/*
获取图片流数据
 */
public static byte[] readStream(InputStream inStream) throws Exception{
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = 0;
    while( (len=inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    outStream.close();
    inStream.close();
    return outStream.toByteArray();
}
```

}

it will be great if some can help,

---

thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to overrride the methods that are essential i.e onNewIntent i.e they are overriden methods of that class

Point on error that a small bulb will appear after clicking that you can implement methods needed.

Answer (score -1):

Please implement onNewIntent()

```
private class RNShareLocalActivityEventListener implements ActivityEventListener {
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == SHARE_REQUEST) {
            callback.invoke("success");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have try that error still shows, i will put the full source on can you please have a look for me cheers advance

Comment: You have to add @Override annotation to the method